# Register User Control Issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control registered at the top of my page:

```
<%@ Register Src="/Controls/User/Navbar.ascx" TagName="Navbar" TagPrefix="pmc" %>
```

and I reference it in my page like this:

```
<pmc:Navbar runat="server" id="navbar"></pmc:Navbar>
```

but it does not know what `<pmc:Navbar` is.  I cannot figure out why.

I'm using VS 2008, in a Web Application Project.

Comment: Given the two generic answers haven't solved this, can you expand upon the specific error you are getting beyond "but it does not know what".  Specifically are you getting auto-complete errors in VS, or runtime exceptions when you compile/run?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should specify the path with ~: ... Src="~/Controls/User/Navbar.ascx" ...

Answer (score 1):

Remove either the initial slash from the path to the control, or better still, prefix it with "~" :

```
<%@ Register Src="Controls/User/Navbar.ascx" TagName="Navbar" TagPrefix="pmc" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/User/Navbar.ascx" TagName="Navbar" TagPrefix="pmc" %>
```

The first solution is flakey as it relies on the page existing in the root folder and the control existing below it.  The second is the preferred as it will work from any page in your project.

You should also consider registering your user controls in your web.config, as it keeps things much neater, and tends to avoid path issues a little better.